# WP_Query orderby not working with meta_value_num and menu_order

Tags: posts, custom-field, wp-query, order

I have made a custom post type (sidebar_element) which are shown on sidebar. On each sidebar element admin can choose where in sidebar should that element be shown, ie. 'top', 'middle' or 'bottom', and that the value is saved in meta field. Meta values for those alignments are 30, 20 and 10.

Now, if there are multiple sidebar elements with same alignment then they should be aligned by their menu_order value given.

This is how I'm trying to achieve all that, in my sidebar.php

```
$sidebarElems   = new WP_Query( array (
                        'post_type'         => 'sidebar_element',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                        'meta_key'          => 'sidebar_element_meta_alignment',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num menu_order',
                        'order'             => 'DESC' ) );
```

This however isn't working. Elements get sorted first by `meta_value_num` **ascending** and then, correctly, by `menu_order`. If I delete the `menu_order` from `orderby`, `meta_values` gets properly ordered.

This thing is driving me crazy!

Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here's the SQL Query generated, when `var_dump($sidebarElems)`

```
SELECT XXX_posts.* FROM XXX_posts
INNER JOIN XXX_postmeta ON (XXX_posts.ID = XXX_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE 1=1 AND XXX_posts.post_type = 'sidebar_element' AND (XXX_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (XXX_postmeta.meta_key = 'sidebar_element_meta_alignment' )
GROUP BY XXX_posts.ID
ORDER BY XXX_postmeta.meta_value+0,XXX_posts.menu_order DESC
```

**ANSWER**
Found an answer, check below

Comment: If you var_dump $sidebarElems, i think you should see the raw SQL somewhere. What does that look like?

Comment: @vancoder Hi, edit my question to include the SQL query. Do you see anything suspicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to this.

Somehow WordPress' own `orderby` isn't fully functional when trying to order by multiple values.

I solved this by changing `WP_Query` to `SQL Query`, and including second `DESC` after `_postmeta.meta_value+0`

```
SELECT XXX_posts.* FROM XXX_posts
INNER JOIN XXX_postmeta ON (XXX_posts.ID = XXX_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE 1=1 AND XXX_posts.post_type = 'sidebar_element' AND (XXX_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (XXX_postmeta.meta_key = 'sidebar_element_meta_alignment' )
GROUP BY XXX_posts.ID
ORDER BY XXX_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC,XXX_posts.menu_order DESC
```